# Keyboard shortcut for autoformat XML request body in SoapUI

Tags: xml, soapui, ready-api

Is there a keyboard shortcut to format SoapUI XML request body? I tried `Alt+F` which didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Alt+F is the combo. Perhaps your expectations don't match the ability of the tool?

When I have this XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
<urn:GetList>
         <urn:Qualification>'1' LIKE "%1"</urn:Qualification>
         <urn:startRecord></urn:startRecord>
         <urn:maxLimit></urn:maxLimit>
</urn:GetList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and press alt+F I get this XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:GetList>
         <urn:Qualification>'1' LIKE "%1"</urn:Qualification>
         <urn:startRecord/>
         <urn:maxLimit/>
      </urn:GetList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Also, you should have your cursor in the XML editing window, otherwise you get the File menu drop down